# VestaCP in Ubuntu 18.04 - Installation errors

Tags: 18.04

I am also having issues with installing [VestaCP](https://vestacp.com/) with Ubuntu 18.04.3 in my DigitalOcean server.  I did install both gnupg and gnupg2 packages in different ubuntu instances and tried installing VestaCP. But in both cases, I am getting errors.

My VestaCP installation command:

> bash vst-install.sh --nginx yes --apache yes --phpfpm no --named no
>   --remi no --vsftpd yes --proftpd no --iptables yes --fail2ban yes --quota no --exim no --dovecot no --spamassassin no --clamav no --softaculous no --mysql yes --postgresql no

Listing the errors that I get after installing gnupg2:

**1. Error A: vesta.service fail**

```
[....] Restarting vesta (via systemctl): vesta.serviceJob for vesta.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status vesta.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

**2. Error B: Can't connect to local MySQL server**

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered creating user:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
dbconfig-common: roundcube configure: noninteractive fail.
dbconfig-common: roundcube configure: ignoring errors from here forwards
```

**3. Error C: Can't load /home/gg/.rnd into RNG**

```
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Can't load /home/gg/.rnd into RNG
140617335595456:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:../crypto/rand/randfile.c:88:Filename=/home/gg/.rnd
```

**4. Error D: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/mysql’: File exists**

```
2019-10-10 18:09:30 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
2019-10-10 18:09:30 [ERROR]   The data directory needs to be specified.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/mysql’: File exists
2019-10-10T18:09:30.532012Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-10-10T18:09:30.538254Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-10-10T18:09:30.538722Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

**Update 1:**

Discussion in VestaCP forum for same issue:

https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=16849&start=70